# How to convert python dictionary with double quotes from single quotes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to perform put_item dynamodb operation through a lambda function written in python. My item looks like -

```
{'Item': {'AccNum': {'S': 'ACC2000000017201'}, 'AdjustmentId': {'N': '0'}}}

Type - <class 'dict'>
```

But dynamodb expects items to be inside double quotes in a dictionary format. I tried using **json.dumps** and it converted each keys to double quotes but it's converting the item to string type instead of dictionary. I can't use string type as dynamodb throws error for type mismatch. Can anyone help me how can I get dictionary item with double quotes in this situation?

Expected o/p :

```
{"Item": {"AccNum": {"S": "ACC2000000017201"}, "AdjustmentId": {"N": "0"}}}

Type - <class 'dict'>
```

Code -

```
import json
import gzip
import boto3
import io

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# Event holds the individual s3 file with backup data
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.Table('mahbis01-AccountService-LedgerSummary-Duplicate')
    
    # Retrieve the bucket name and file name from event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    json_object = s3.Object(bucket, json_file_name)
    buf = io.BytesIO(json_object.get()['Body'].read())
    for line in gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf):
        line = json.loads(line)
        table.put_item(Item=line)
```

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key AccNum in the item"
```

Comment: Either you need a dictionary, in which case it'll be shown with single quotes by default (unless there's a single quote in the string), or you need a JSON-formatted string. It's unclear how you're trying to use this.

Comment: Please include your boto3 code and any errors you see. The quotes issue is a red herring and is a misunderstanding of Python and dictionaries.

Comment: There's no difference to Python. Boto3 should accept a dict object, either way. `json.dumps` wouldn't convert the item value to a string unless it's actually a string

Comment: I'm reading a zipped JSON file in my code and trying to insert items to dynamodb as dictionary objects @jarmod

Comment: If that example dictionary is the item you want to insert, then you should insert the item with something like `table.put_item(Item=json.loads(line)['Item'])`

Comment: I'm already doing ```line = json.loads(line); table.put_item(Item=line['Item'])``` but getting issue for quotes @AnonCoward

Comment: JSON parsing issues aside, your JSON file content is incompatible with your use of the DynamoDB Table resource. Your JSON file is in a format suitable for the Client interface (`boto3.client('dynamodb').put_item(Item)`), not the Resource interface. The Client interface requires you to indicate attribute types e.g. `'name': { 'S': 'abcd' }` whereas the Resource interface infers the type: `'name': 'abcd'`.

Comment: put_item worked with your suggestion, thanks @jarmod

Comment: I added an answer. Please accept if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file content is incompatible with your use of the DynamoDB Table resource. You should use the Client interface, for example:

```
boto3.client('dynamodb').put_item(Item)
```

The Client interface requires you to indicate attribute types (e.g. String, Number), for example:

```
'name': { 'S': 'abcd' }
```

The Resource interface infers the data type from Python native types, for example:

```
'name': 'abcd'
```